# Sorting a struct array or dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a struct dictionary like this (Taken from [Swift: How to declare a 2d array (grid or matrix) in Swift to allow random insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563821/swift-how-to-declare-a-2d-array-grid-or-matrix-in-swift-to-allow-random-inser) , thanks to @rintaro ):

```
struct Matrix2D<KeyElem:Hashable, Value> {

    var _storage:[KeyElem:[KeyElem:Value]] = [:]

    subscript(x:KeyElem, y:KeyElem) -> Value? {
        get {
            return _storage[x]?[y]
        }
        set(val) {
            if _storage[x] == nil {
                _storage[x] = [:]
            }
            _storage[x]![y] = val
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to sort this dictionary by x, but I can't find a way to achieve this. Is it event possible to sort a dictionary? Or should I maybe use the solution with an Array instead of a Dictionary?

```
struct Matrix2D<T> {

    var _storage:[[T?]] = []

    subscript(x:Int, y:Int) -> T? {
        get {
            if _storage.count <= x {
            return nil
            }
            if _storage[x].count <= y {
                return nil
            }
            return _storage[x][y]
        }
        set(val) {
            if _storage.count <= x {
                let cols = [[T?]](count: x - _storage.count + 1, repeatedValue: [])
                _storage.extend(cols)
            }
            if _storage[x].count <= y {
                let rows = [T?](count: y - _storage[x].count + 1, repeatedValue: nil)
                _storage[x].extend(rows)
            }
            _storage[x][y] = val
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is your motivation for sorting? if it's simply for quicker lookup, note that lookup for a Dictionary is already fast (hence the reason that the keys conform to `Hashable`) - if we knew your reasoning, it might be easier to offer a possible solution

Comment: Ok, I want to use this struct to map coordinates with an integer. The coordinates describe a field in a grid, the integer by how many fields each field is going to be moved in the grid. I need to have the array sorted, that i wont get problems when it comes to actually moving the fields. Of course, i could just loop an array containing all keys of _storage to get the values in the right order, but I wondered if there was a cleaner solution. Hope this gives you an idea of how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is per definition a collection type containing unordered key - value pairs.

There are some solutions for ordered dictionaries using a backing array, see for example [earning-swift-ordered-dictionaries](http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/)